# Loaded styles and css but not displaying properly

Tags: php, html, css, import

So I tried to import a web HTML CSS template into my self-made MVC.
When I open the template itself it works properly. But when I access it through my controller it can not connect to CSS files and does not display proper style. Only blank HTML without any styles.
This is how I am trying to access it

```
class NewsController {

public function actionIndex() {
    $newsList = array();
    $newsList = News::getNewsList();

    require_once 'views/index.php';

    return true;
}
```

This is code from HTML head where it links the CSS

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

this is how folders are located(highlited the controller, and views folders is a full template ) folders tree:

[image]

EDIT
I checked with inspec all the elements are loaded but do not display any styles. Whats the matter?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'./'` at start of CSS paths. This allow browser to use absolute file path.

Comment: Did it this way
nothing changed
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/animate.css" >

Answer (score 0):

./ is has nothing to do with an absolute file path. It just marks the current direcory.

If you want to use the absolute filepath, do it with php or the equivalent in your template language:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo __ DIR __ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'blogv4' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'views' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'css' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'animate.css'; ?>" />
```

?>

EDIT: Due to the image of your folder tree you can write:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="blogv4/views/css/animate.css" />
```

You need to enter the path from your bootstrap file (e. g. index.php), which contains your header.

Comment: Please could you make an example 
I am not so advanced in php :(

Comment: So i wrote All of this in the same place it was before, just change the route?
Did not help either :(

Comment: It was just a suggestion in case you want/need to use an absolute URL. If you want to stick to a relative URL in HTML, then please try: <link rel="stylesheet" href="blogv4/views/css/animate.css" /> 

The location of your controller is not relevant in this case.

Comment: @Asisito If I may: the absolute path using `__DIR__` is not a good idea, because the css/js resources are visible to anyone.

Comment: the CSS resources are visible to anyone else because their path is in your sourcecode. by clicking on the link - not depending if url is absolute or not - everyone can see.

Comment: @Asisito I meant: no one must see an absolute path of the **file system**, like "C:\MyProjects\blogV4\views\..." (which is resolved by the magical `__DIR__`). One should use a **web** absolute path, like: "www.myblog.com/assets/css..." to access the css/js resources, or a **web** relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PHP script (in your case, the index.php handling the request) that's calling your Controllers lives in your document root where your assets are. 
And, if I am the one, I'd write an helper function for handling my assets, like

```
<?php
    function asset($resource) {
        $link = preg_replace('/\//', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $resource);
        return $link;
    }
?>
```

Like that, you can render the absolute path of where your assets are by adding the protocol and domain prefix in front on the return value.